# Chrome doesn't get my new code from server. How can I Fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

When I reload the chrome to see the new code, it reload the old one.
I write new code, deploy it to the server. 
The same thing happens when I build the server and check the new code on the chrome.
So every time change occur in the code, I have to hard reload the chrome.
I want to stop hard reload..
How can I Fix it in code?
Thanks to read.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to help you, sadly. Are you using Create React App? Try to unregister the service worker.

Comment: @Tholle yes, I'm using Create React App and Apache. 
Is the service worker related to this problem? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @grooveplex Thanks for your comment! But I want to automatically fetch new code from the server without having to refresh the cache every time.

Comment: Yes, if you check the [comment at the bottom of you `index.js` file](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/index.js) you might be registering a service worker. Try to unregister it if that's the case.